# How I draw the tree of possibility?

Tags: chessboard

I can do the following drawings of Board:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\let\boardfont\undefinedcommand
\usepackage{diagram}

\begin{document}
\setboolean{showcomputer}{false}
\setboolean{piececounter}{false}
\specialdiagnum{}

\begin{diagram}[4x4]
\pieces{wDa3, wDb1, wDc4, wDd2}
\end{diagram}
\begin{diagram}[4x4]
\pieces{wDb4}
\end{diagram}

\end{document}
```

But, as do the tree of possibilities:[image]

Comment: Please stylize the code of question.

Comment: I recommend setting things up so that you avoid the use of metafont source if possible. Right now, your document uses chess pieces in metafont form rather than the type1 versions of the fonts. If you are creating PDF, it would be better by far to use the type1 versions.

Comment: @cfr: the diagram package has the metafont fonts hardcoded. It is not easily possible to switch to type1 fonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh. That's a shame.

Comment: Could you please review answers to [your other questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36688/benedito?tab=questions), benedito? In particular, you've received some truly oustanding answers to [How to make dominoes falling?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149828/how-to-make-dominoes-falling) You should accept your favourite one. That's the best way to say "thank you", on TeX.SX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's something to get you started, using [`tikz`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz) and the idea of `trees`

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        level 1/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm},
        level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm},
        level distance=2cm,
    ]
    \node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}
    child {
        node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
        child {node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}}
        child {
            node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
            child {node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-c}}}
        }
    }
    child {
        node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
        child {
            node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
            child {
                node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-c}}
                child {node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}}
            }
        }
    }
    child {
        node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
        child {
            node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
            child {
                node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-c}}
                child {node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}}
            }
        }
    }
    child {
        node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
        child {
            node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
            child {node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-c}}}
        }
        child {node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

and something that does the borders:

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        level 1/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm,},
        level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm},
        special/.style={draw=red,thick,double,inner sep=0mm},
        level distance=3cm,
        line width=3,
    ]
    \node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}
    child {
        node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
        child {node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}}
        child {
            node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
            child {node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-c}}}
        }
    }
    child {
        node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
        child {
            node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
            child {
                node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-c}}
                child {node[special] {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}}
            }
        }
    }
    child {
        node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
        child {
            node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
            child {
                node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-c}}
                child {node[special]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}}
            }
        }
    }
    child {
        node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
        child {
            node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
            child {node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-c}}}
        }
        child {node {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Tweak as you see fit `:)`

Answer (score 6):

You could always, of course, use `forest`:

[image: chess in the forest]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\let\boardfont\undefinedcommand
\usepackage{diagram}

\begin{document}
\setboolean{showcomputer}{false}
\setboolean{piececounter}{false}

\specialdiagnum{}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}, shorten <=-15pt, line width=2.5pt] (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
  }
  [{\begin{diagram}[4x4]\end{diagram}}
    [{\begin{diagram}[4x4]\pieces{wDa4}\end{diagram}}
      [{\begin{diagram}[4x4]\pieces{wDa4, wDc3}\end{diagram}}]
      [{\begin{diagram}[4x4]\pieces{wDa4, wDd3}\end{diagram}}
        [{\begin{diagram}[4x4]\pieces{wDa4, wDd3, wDb2}\end{diagram}}]
      ]
    ]
    [{\begin{diagram}[4x4]\pieces{wDb4}\end{diagram}}
      [{\begin{diagram}[4x4]\pieces{wDb4, wDd3}\end{diagram}}
        [{\begin{diagram}[4x4]\pieces{wDb4, wDd3, wDa2}\end{diagram}}
          [{\begin{diagram}[4x4]\pieces{wDb4, wDd3, wDa2, wDc1}\end{diagram}}]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [{\begin{diagram}[4x4]\pieces{wDc4}\end{diagram}}
      [{\begin{diagram}[4x4]\pieces{wDc4, wDa3}\end{diagram}}
        [{\begin{diagram}[4x4]\pieces{wDc4, wDa3, wDd2}\end{diagram}}
          [{\begin{diagram}[4x4]\pieces{wDc4, wDa3, wDd2, wDb1}\end{diagram}}]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [{\begin{diagram}[4x4]\pieces{wDd4}\end{diagram}}
      [{\begin{diagram}[4x4]\pieces{wDd4, wDa3}\end{diagram}}
        [{\begin{diagram}[4x4]\pieces{wDd4, wDa3, wDc2}\end{diagram}}]
      ]
      [{\begin{diagram}[4x4]\pieces{wDd4, wDb3}\end{diagram}}]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```